# Getting Rails app postgreSQL information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this rails app which is running on my Mac somehow. It's connected to a PG database and it's working great.

The problem is, I have no idea how to access the database. When I check the database.yml file, this is what I get:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: shop_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: shop_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Accessing the rails console on the application, and running:

```
Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
```

Yields:

```
=> {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"shop_development", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
```

I'm trying desperately to connect to that database from another computer in the network, using pgAdmin III, but no avail. I tried writing the local network ip address in the host field, and the default port, with username "admin" and blank password, but it tells me "Server doesn't listen".

Maybe someone can help me out.

Comment: I think you need to check PostgreSQL config files

Comment: Server not listening suggests your mac isn't listening on the port the postgres server runs on (normally 5432)

Comment: @AmitSharma Where are those?

Comment: If you want to connect to your Postgresql instance from outside, you have to setup [pg_hba](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) That is completely not related to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I'm also trying to access locally on the Mac. Gives me a different error, tho: "Role 'admin' does not exist". Maybe it IS at localhost, default port? Need to figure out the credentials.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. The username was my Mac username, no password. Guess that's what happens after 20 hours straight work. Thanks for the help, guys.